# How to prevent csrf attack if jwt token stored in cookie with httponly in laravel and Vue spa?

Tags: laravel, authentication, vue.js, jwt, csrf

Frontend: Vue spa

Backend: laravel

Frontend and backend are separated, and they are communited with xhr request.

In the beginning I use local storage to store the JWT token, but now I found out that is not very secure.

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Same question here Hexor, any update on this?

Comment: I'am also looking for a solution for this.

Answer (score -2):

Add the csrf_token in your html head as a meta tag

```
<meta id="token" name="token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then in your Vue.js Main File add this token to your Vue Instance.

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('content');
```

Comment: Thank you. But my front end page is separated from back end, and it is all static page. So I can not use csrf_token() because it runs by php.